# How to reload widgets from the share sheet, via an Action Extension

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

My app has an action extension that allow users to collect and save links throughout the system. It also has a widget to show these links in the Home Screen.

When adding links from the main app, I call `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` to reload all widgets, and everything works as expected.

But when I add links from the action extension, widgets are not reloaded, even after calling `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()`. Only when I go to the main app is that widgets do reload.

How can I refresh my widgets for changes made via the Action Extension from the share sheet?